# Wrapping a C program that contains a main function into a C++ class,

Tags: c++, c, class, wrapper, program-entry-point

I am recently asked to wrap a C program that contains a main function into a C++ class, but I do not see the general approach to do it effectively.

For example, my C program is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
        int i, sum = 0;

        if (argc != 3) {
                printf("Two numbers are needed.\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("The sum is :%d \n ", atoi(argv[1])+atoi(argv[2]));


}
```

How can I wrap this main function into a C++ class? My vague idea is to use C++ constructor to simulate main's argc and argv, but I don't know how. Cam you help?

Comment: Is your question how to change the code so that it’s naturally class-based?  Or how, at a technical level, to wrap an unchangeable .c file containing `main`?

Comment: A main function will be the same for C++ and C program, there is no difference between how OS will start your program.

What you can do is create a class and intantiate it on a main program and call methods (C++), or just call functions on your main and pass parameters (C).

Your example is so simple, there is no better way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
class program {
public:
  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, sum = 0;

    if (argc != 3) {
      printf("Two numbers are needed.\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("The sum is :%d \n ", atoi(argv[1])+atoi(argv[2]));
    return 0; // WE MUST DO THIS NOW! 
  }
};

// actual main for testing
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   program p;
   return p.main(argc, argv);
}
```

We could make it so that the constructor is the main function, but that seems like a poor idea; if we put any content into the `program` class, the main function might want its construction to be complete before being called.

Comment: Why not make it a static function since you have no members to use? Or heck, why even make it a class at all? Why not just have `cmain(int argc, ...)`? Unless we have more info from OP, I'm not sure this is the best way.

Comment: This is technically a solution, but one that goes against a lot of software design principles. The `program` class should have a well defined mandate, not something like "take input, validate input and convert a bunch of stuff" as one function. There's an opportunity here to separate those into different concerns and it's not even hard to do it.

Comment: @tadman The `program` class shouldn't have anything in it that isn't in the requirement specification. Implementing a whole lot of stuff that is not in the requirements goes against business and software engineering principles. [The King's Toaster](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/ktoast.html).

Comment: @kaz I'm not talking about implementing different functionality, but adhering to principles like [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) which advise on how to *structure* solutions which implement that functionality. This example is literally "put the stuff that would otherwise go in `main()` inside a class" which is not what classes are supposed to do. The class itself is utterly extraneous here and adds no value because it's not used correctly.

Comment: @kaz Arguably the best toaster ever made has *zero* electronics in it because of [elegant engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OfxlSG6q5Y). There's a big difference between over-engineering, which is the King's toaster, and proper engineering.

Comment: @tadman Though the class adds no value (the original program works without it), there is a requirement for it coming from somewhere, and that's what the question is about. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't anything obviously incorrect about how the class is used. I have now compiled and run the code; it needed some `#include` directives for `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>`, and GNU C++ warns about unused variables `i` and `sum`. I'm aware that the `atoi` function has undefined behavior on out of range inputs, and that `+` can overflow. That's just the code from the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard. Just delegate the conversion to the `main()` function, and pass through the correct values:

```
SumComputer computer(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]));

printf("The sum is :%d \n ", computer.sum());
```

Where you have a class with a constructor like `SumComputer(const int a, const int b)` and an `int sum() const` function.

You could also have an object that has a simple constructor and a more complex `sum()` function, perhaps even using [varargs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic).